# html input boxes misaligned in print page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an html form, after submission of the form, user is taken to different page showing their entered values, below the display will be print button. below is some code for the printable page

```css
<style>
    .input-w label {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .input-w input {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;

    }

.zebra {margin-top:1815px;}
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .zebra {margin-top:20px;}
}
    </style>
```

```html
<div ><a href="index.html"><img src="web\img\teia.PNG" alt="" width="300" height="135"></a></div>
<br>
<h6 align="center"><b>Member Registration Form</b></h6>
<br>
<!-- <h3 class="main_question"><strong>1/5</strong>Primary Applicant Name</h3> -->
<div class="input-w">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>First Name:</label>
       <input type="text" style="width:400px; height:37px;" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $name;?>" readonly>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="input-w">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" style="width:400px; height:37px;" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $lastname ?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-w">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Company Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="company" style="width:400px; height:37px;" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $company?>" readonly>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="input-w">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Designation:</label>
      <input type="text" name="designation" style="width:400px; height:37px;" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $designation?>" readonly>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="input-w">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="company" style="width:400px; height:37px;" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $address?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-w">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>City:</label>
      <input type="text" name="designation" style="width:400px; height:37px;" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $city?>" readonly>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="input-w">
```

now when the user clicks the print button, the boxes are misaligned like in the following pic
[image]
my form page is like following
[image]

i want to align the box properly in the print page so that it comes properly when user prints the page. without effecting my form page. does anyun has idea about this

Comment: you have to put form inside the table , only then it will work

Comment: @RaviKadyan can you show me as an answer with my code

Comment: i can show you an example.

Comment: @RaviKadyan yes please

Comment: here the link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/867331/create-a-form-using-html-tables/   you have to put content for ex Name and input in a same row of a table ..go through this example

Comment: it's alright...